# Is $M_R\otimes _R {_R}N\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes_{\mathbb Z} {_{\mathbb Z}}N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, tensor-products

Suppose $M$ is a right $R-$module and $N$ is a left $R-$ module. Also $M$ and $N$ are naturally $Z-$ module, both in left and right side. So we will denote $M_R$, $M_{\mathbb Z}$, and $_RN, _{\mathbb Z}N$ for modules $M$ and $N$ over different rings.

Now, we can write $M_R$ as $$M_R\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R$$ where $R$ can be regard as $\mathbb Z-R$ bimodule, so $$M_R\otimes _R {_R}N\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R\otimes _RN$$ but on the other hand, ${_{\mathbb Z}}R_R\otimes _R{_R}N$is isomorphic to $ _{\mathbb Z}N$ as left $\mathbb Z$-module, so $$M_R\otimes _R {_R}N\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R\otimes _RN\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes_{\mathbb Z} {_{\mathbb Z}}N$$

If true, but intuitively, tensor product over ring $R$ should be smaller, but we get isomorphism; If not true, where am I wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: Try thinking about the case $M=N=R$.

Comment: Or try thinking about your first displayed equation when $M=R={\mathbb Z}[x]$.

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect. All of the Zs should be replaced by Rs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by  Qiaochu Yuan, the first isomorphism fails in general: $M_R\not\cong M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R$

Example: Take $M=R:=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ the Gaussian integers:

As $\mathbb{Z}$-module, $M\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$. Hence $M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R\cong R_R \oplus R_R \cong \mathbb{Z}^4$ where the last isomorphism is an isomorphism of abelian groups. So $M_R$ and $M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes _{\mathbb Z}{_{\mathbb Z}}R_R$ are not even isomorphic as abelian groups.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was previously thinking $M_{\mathbb Z}\otimes_{\mathbb Z} R$ has natural right $R$ module structure, but it is not $M_R$, indeed.